# Is there any way to put in a undefined-sized array and be inherited as a static one?

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, struct

I'm wondering if there is a way for an array in a class/struct to have no exact set value, so when it's inherited, it could have a different value than other structures. In this example:

```cpp
struct foo
{
    virtual int test[];
};
struct bar : foo
{
    int test[3];
};
struct bars : foo
{
    int test[5]
};
```

In this example, I try to define a new int array having a virtual keyword in the `foo` class. As you can see that `bar`'s test array is size 3, but in `bars`'s test array is size 5. However, when I try to inherit `foo` to `bar` or `bars`, it fails and gives me an error: `invalid base class`.

Edit: Sorry that my post wasn't exactly clear. I was trying best to explain an unknown-sized array, but somehow ended up with something more confusing. Also, for the people who are going to say use `std::vector`, please re-read my edits above

Comment: `virtual int test[];` is not a virtual *function*

Answer (score 0):

Is there a workaround to this? Better yet, is there something more efficient than an array that allows the capabilities of being a new static array from an inherited dynamic array?

Use std::vector in base class... and make it protected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Regardless, you could use;

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int* t) : test(t) {}
    int* test;
};
struct bar : foo
{
    bar() : foo(derived_test) {}

    int derived_test[3];
};
```

It will be a lot better to use `std::vector<int>` though.

```
struct foo
{
    foo(size_t size) : test(size) {}
    std::vector<int> test;
};
struct bar : foo
{
    bar() : foo(3) {}
};
```